# How to express $\lfloor(3+\sqrt{3})^n\rfloor$ with a formula?

Tags: number-theory

We suppose that $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$

Now I can express $\lfloor(2+\sqrt{3})^n\rfloor$ with a formula by this way:

we know that:
$$
(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
and also:
$$
0 < (2-\sqrt{3})^n < 1
$$
so we know that the fractional part of $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ is:
$$
1-(2-\sqrt{3})^n
$$
so the integral part of $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ is:
$$
(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n-1
$$

But there are some differences with $(3+\sqrt{3})^n$. My question is: How to express the integral part of $(3+\sqrt{3})^n$ with a formula just like before description?

Comment: If we define $x:=3+\sqrt{3}$ and $y:=3-\sqrt{3}$ , $x^n+y^n$ is an integer for all $n\ge 1$, but unfortunately $y^n$ does not converge to $0$. This is the difference making the problem harder

Comment: Not sure if it helps: $(3+\sqrt 3)^2=6(2+\sqrt 3)$